# Rails insert new record to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have table Repairs with id, name
in controller:

```
@Repairs = Repair.all
```

How to add new id=0, name="new_name" in @Repairs array before all records not in database
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@repairs = Repair.all
@new_repire = Repair.new(:name => "new_name, :other_parameter => "something)
@new_repire.id = 0
@Repairs.unshitf @new_repire
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@repair = Repair.new(:id => 0, :name => "new_name, :other_parameter => "something)
```

Do you really need the id before saving? Usually best to let Rails take care of that.